# PostgreSQL Clob datatype

Tags: database, postgresql, types, clob

PostgreSQL supports both `clob` and `text` data types for storing large texts. I've used `clob` data type as we are migrating the DB from Oracle. I understand that the `clob` data type in PostgreSQL can only store up to 1GB of text rather than the 4GB in oracle.

Since my text size is well below 1GB, I am fine with using either of these types. So can I use PostgreSQL clob datatype or is there any advantage for `text` datatype over `clob`?

Any help will be much appreciated and Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The `clob` data type is [unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unsupported-features-sql-standard.html) in Postgres. However, it can be easily defined as a synonym to the `text` type:

```
create domain clob as text;
```